# How compiler behaves on out of range char value?

Tags: c, char, type-conversion

```
char ch = 1107;
printf("ch = %c", ch);
```

Above code prints S.

I do not get how this happens. I am giving an out of range value for char type. How compiler gets this value "S" (ASCII 83)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run this demonstrative program

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    printf( "%#x\n", 1107 );
    printf( "%c\n", 0x53 );

    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
0x453
S
```

So as it is seen the compiler just extracts the lowest byte of the integer constant and assign the stored value to the object of the type char,

Comment: I don't understand your demonstration. Particularly not the 53.

Comment: wouldn't be `printf("%d\n", (char) 1107);` a better example to show the behaviour?

Comment: @PaulOgilvie This value 453 is a hex representation of the constant 1107. So the lowest byte contains 53 and is assigned to the object ch. It would be more coorectly to write char ch = ( char )1107;

Comment: So the `53` should be `0x53`.

Comment: The example is still unclear. I suggest the second line should be `printf( "%c\n", 0x1153 );` as now the high-byte (`0x11`) will be "chopped off" and only the low byte (`0x53`) will be printed and that is the letter S.

Answer (score 1):

If 1107 is too big to fit into a `char` (it usually is but a `char` might be larger than 8 bits), and `char` is `unsigned`, then 1107 is converted to a `char` with the normal wrap-around behaviour. If `char` is `signed` then the conversion is implementation-defined and an implementation-defined signal might be raised.

After this `ch` is widened to an `int` as it's passed on the variable argument list.

Internally, inside `printf`, that `int` is converted to an `unsigned char`, with normal *wrap-around* rules applying.

Comment: Why are you subtracting? Are you taking modulus?

Comment: @Lyrk: I tinned that part, since the crux of the question is the type of `ch`: all the impactful narrowing conversions happen there.